# Get a TextWriter for the console

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am using `CsvHelper`, which uses a `TextWriter` to write its output. Instead of writing to a file, I would like to write the contents to the console. How can I get a `TextWriter` that will write to the console?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`Console.Out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx) property to get the `TextWriter` for the console, like so:

```
var textWriter = Console.Out;

using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
    textWriter.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Why you asking question if you know answer?

Comment: @Reniuz http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer ... Reasonable question, reasonable answer - so what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Reniuz This is allowed and encouraged on this site. See Jeff's reasoning here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, just didn't knew that you can answer right away :)

Comment: Disposing Console.Out with the *using* statement is a Bad Idea.

Comment: That still doesn't work, Console.Out still gets disposed by CsvSerializer.Dispose().  Have you tested this at all?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Console.Out` is still available. I am still able to use the `TextWriter` and write to the console after the above code is run. How do I determine whether or not `Console.Out` has been disposed?

Comment: @RyanKohn For CsvWriter to not take ownership of the underlying stream, the constructor `new CsvWriter(textWriter, true)` could be used.